# Remove item from session array

Tags: php, session

I am having trouble removing an item from the itinerary/array upon clicking a 'Remove location' link.

The value of the location to be removed is passed into the 'remove_loc.php' file as its unique 'loc_id' and assigned to a new variable. Upon doing this I then try to use 'unset()' to delete it from the session array but it doesn't seem to be working.

The value of the location is definitely being passed through to the 'remove_loc.php' file ok as I have run an echo statement at other end to make sure, and am connecting ok to db etc, so I believe the error is in my remove_loc.php file.

Code for itinerary.php (where locations are displayed).Note 'Remove Location' href link:

```
<?php

session_start();

include ("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
include("includes/head.html");
include("includes/search_box.html");
include("includes/left_sidebar.html");


//If user not already logged in then redirect to the login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    load_page();

    }//if

    //Display contents of itinerary
    if(!empty($_SESSION['itinerary'])){

        //Retrieve details of each location in array from database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE loc_id IN (";
        foreach ($_SESSION['itinerary'] as $loc_id=>$value)
        {$query.=$loc_id.',';}
        $query = substr($query, 0, -1).')ORDER BY loc_id ASC';
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    echo'<form action="itinerary.php" method="POST"><table><tr><th colspan="5">Locations in your itinerary<br></br></th></tr><tr>';

    //Display locations in array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        $loc_id = $row['loc_id'];

        echo"<tr><td>{$row['loc_name']}<br></br></td>
        <td>{$row['loc_desc']}</td>
        <td><a href=remove_loc.php?value=$loc_id>Remove location</a><br></br></td>
        ";
    }//while


    mysqli_close($db);

    }//if

    else {echo '<p>Your itinerary is empty.<br></br></p>';}

echo '<p>

<a href=submit.php?submit=$submission>Save itinerary</a><br></br>
<a href="user_details.php">Your details</a><br></br>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br></br>
</p>';


?>
```

Code for 'remove_loc.php' (for removing location from session array):

```
<?php

session_start();

include ("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
include("includes/head.html");
include("includes/search_box.html");
include("includes/left_sidebar.html");

?>

<html>

<h1>REMOVE LOCATION</h1>
<br></br>

<?php

//If user not already logged in then redirect to the login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    load_page();

    }//if

//Assign ID of location which has been passed to new variable
if(isset($_GET['value']))
    $loc_id = $_GET['value'];
//Remove location from sess array?
if(isset($_SESSION['itinerary'][$loc_id])) unset($_SESSION['itinerary'][$loc_id]);
echo 'Removal successful!';

print_r($_SESSION);


?>

</html>
```

Comment: tldr, but to delete an item from session, or from any array for that matter, use unset..... `unset($_SESSION['index_to_delete']);`

Comment: you should fix your html. there's no such thing as a `</br>` tag. breaks are singletons. `<br />`. Why do you have a `<form>`, but not input tags?

Comment: your code looks fine as far as i can see.. what leads you to believe it's not working?

Comment: I'm running a print_r statement and whenever I click on the Remove Location link it displays the array/itinerary with nothing removed. I have tried the 'unset' function without adding in the $loc_id variable and it deletes the whole array as it should. But I just want to delete that one location whose identity has been passed in.

Comment: all i can say is unset is correct: http://ideone.com/OO1QlU